# Why are there so many backslashes (\) in the *.prof file?

Tags: haskell

Looking into the `*.prof` file generated using `+RTS -p` with profiling enabled compilation, I see a lot of these sub-routines that named `\`:

```
COST CENTRE           MODULE                         %time %alloc

main.\.\.\            Main                            74.1   85.8
unstreamChunks/inner  Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Fusion  11.9    8.6 
inverseLetters.\      Main                             4.5    1.7 
main.\.\.\.(...)      Main                             2.9    1.0 
main.\.\.\.(...)      Main                             2.8    1.0 
unstreamChunks/resize Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Fusion   1.2    0.8 
unstreamChunks/outer  Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Fusion   1.1    0.5
```

which looks cryptic to me. What do these represent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let

```
import Control.Monad

main = do
    forM_ [1..1000] $ \i ->
        if mod i 2 == 0 then putStrLn "Foo"
                        else print i
```

and run with

```
ghc -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto z.hs && ./z +RTS -p && cat z.prof
```

then, following [rules to set cost centres](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#prof-rules)

```
COST CENTRE MODULE           %time %alloc
main.\      Main              80.0   84.4
main        Main              20.0   13.2
CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD   0.0    2.1
```

the backslashes show that stack level, [you can set names for each one](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#scc-pragma)

```
forM_ [1..1000] $ \i ->
    {-# SCC "myBranch" #-}
    if mod i 2 == 0 then putStrLn "Foo"
                    else print i
```

and now

```
COST CENTRE MODULE           %time %alloc
myBranch    Main              90.0   84.4
main        Main              10.0   13.2
CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD   0.0    2.1
```

(Added @trVoldemort comment)

Also, `(...)` seems to be used for `let` assignments with computations involved

```
data T = T Int (IO ()) (IO ())
main =
   forM_ [T (mod i 2) (putStrLn "Foo") (print i) | i <- [1..1000]] $ \q ->
        let T a b c = q -- Will be `(...)`
        in  if a == 0 then b else c
```

with profile output

```
main.\        Main
 main.\.b     Main
 main.\.c     Main
 main.\.(...) Main
 main.\.a     Main
```

with SCC pragma

```
forM_ [T (mod i 2) (putStrLn "Foo") (print i) | i <- [1..1000]] $ \q ->
     let T a b c = {-# SCC "myBind" #-} q
     in  if a == 0 then b else c
```

and output

```
main.\.b     Main
main.\.c     Main
main.\.(...) Main
 myBind      Main
main.\.a     Main
```

Comment: So, these are no backslashes, they are lambdas in disguise. Interesting.

Comment: @chi: Not even much of a disguise since that's the syntax we normally have for lambdas :).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. On a side note, I realized that the `.(...)` after some `./` represents a let statement with pattern matching (which means it involves computation). For example, when you say `let (a, b) = myFunc` or `let Just x = lookup ...` etc.